# how to stop debugger breaks in locked source code I didnt write vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using visual studio 2010 prof. When I am testing the program and I hit an Unhandled Exception from Access violation or such, the debugger often breaks in these locked source files which i think are part of the libraries im using. I recall this happened quite a few times when an uninitialized var was used in an array like:

```
myArray[var]
```

where the var was not initialized and has some large negative value. But when this happens I can't figure out how to see the last line of "my code / the code I wrote" where this Exception happened. Trying to step in or how will just re create the unhanded exception. I looked through my debugging options to see if i could perhaps turn this off. But perhaps there is a way. It takes an awful long time to find the problem when I have no idea where to look for the problem.

again I just want to see the line on "my code / the code I wrote" where the exception occurred.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
this is what i see in the call stack after the exception occures:

```
    SDL.dll!00206280()  
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for SDL.dll]   
    Uber Mario.exe!_main()  + 0x6c bytes    C
    Uber Mario.exe!_WinMain@16()  + 0x101 bytes C
    Uber Mario.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 547 + 0x1c bytes   C
>   kernel32.dll!76ab339a()     
    ntdll.dll!77789ef2()    
    ntdll.dll!77789ec5()
```

nothing in there makes any sense to me as functions or code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a look at the stack trace to find out which of your function caused the exception.

You get such a call stack because nothing in language prevents you to access
 `myArray[var] // say var is uninitialised`.
 But the language runtime in windows checks if you are accessing valid area for security reason. So basically in your case **runtime throws the exception, not your code**. 

If you're in c/c++ you'd get an exception like:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'var' is being used without being initialized.
```

Break the execution, you'd get the currently executing line, that caused the failure.

Comment: see this two link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439516(v=vs.85).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

Comment: im not sure if this is the case for the exception I am having now. I just used that uninitialized array example because i think that was the case another time.

Comment: If implementation throws exception you can't really know, for which line in your code it did so.